# Taking too much time to finish the Activity in Android?

Tags: android, performance, flash, android-webview

I have loading the webview in my Activity. the Web content is having some flash content. when i try to finish the Activity. Its taking too much time. the screen goes to blank screen for little time and resuming to the app.

Is there any Idea to fix this issue??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

which version you are using...???? above android 3.x versions only support flash. Below 3.x wont support flash for this reason only you are getting blank screen. try with above 3.x versions.